# App crashes when restoring from background

Tags: java, android

I have static values that are deleted after my application is a long time in the background or after opening many different apps, causing that my app crashes.
I think that Android OS is removing data from my app or "killing" it.
Is there any way to keep my app's data to avoid this problem?

NOTE: I can't save this values on `SharedPreferences` or in a database because there are many `HashMaps` and `ArrayLists`, is too much information.
It is necessary that these values are static because I need them available in many classes o my app in any time.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.proyect/com.proyect.gui.ActivityMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
 at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
 at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
 at com.proyect.gui.FragmentMenu.onActivityCreated(FragmentMenu.java:145)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1983)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:174)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your log cat of crash?

Comment: static values should not get deleted that way. Like Sri asked, share your logCat

Comment: You cannot prevent the OS from killing your app, so there's no avoiding the need to save your data in some kind of persistent storage.

Comment: The log shows a null pointer exception, I have a try/catch and the app is crashing in the catch, in a "Log.v("errorTag", e.getMessage());"
In the "try" I'm trying to get data from a static HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Log.v("errorTag", e.getMessage());
```

To this:

```
String error = e.getMessage();
if(error == null)
    error = "It's crashed here";
Log.v("errorTag", error );
```

**OR SIMPLER**

```
Log.v("errorTag", e );
```

The point is that e.getMessage() is null. So, always check if e.getMessage() is not null before print it

Comment: The problem is that I need the static values in more clases, if I do this, the app will crash in another class because the static values will remain null. I need to keep the values.

Comment: The point is that e.getMessage() is null... So, there's nothing you can do... it is null... e.getMessage() can return null... So, always check if e.getMessage() is not null before print it

Comment: I can remove all e.getMessage(), I can  check if e.getMessage() is not null in all classes, but the problem is that the static values that I need are null when I restore the app from the background. That is the problem,

Comment: Ok... So, update your question with proper code which is null... In the comments, you mentioned this line was causing the error... If there's another code which has issues, please, post to your question